# Парсинг json VK с помощью SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, вконтакте

Нужно с помощью SwiftyJSON из json ответа VK получить некоторые значения, например id из первого items.
(начало примера ответа из оффициального api VK)

```
response: {
count: 617,
items: [{
id: 67640,
from_id: -86529522,
owner_id: -86529522,
date: 1465326080,
post_type: 'post',
text: 'Создатель [club41960539|Крошки Ши] на VK Fest'
```

Для этого пытаюсь использовать следующий код

```
let urlPath: String = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let stringPost="access_token=" + token // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        do {

            if let jsonResult = try JSON(data: data!) as? JSON {

               print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)end")

                if let id = jsonResult["response"]["items"][0]["id"].string {
                    print("\(id) ID")
                }
```

Но строка if let id = jsonResult["response"]["items"][0]["id"].string никогда не является истиной, т.е. где то появляется nil. При этом, пробовал выводить jsonResult в терминал, там видно вот это

```
{
  "response" : [
    655,
    {
      "id" : 830,
      "comments" : {
        "count" : 0,
        "can_post" : 1
      },
      "reply_count" : 0,
      "can_delete" : 1,
```

Немного не то, что описанно в оффициальном api вконтакте. В каком месте я допускаю ошибку?

Comment: Думаю что ошибка где то у меня, теряются некоторые значения в процессе преобразования полученных данных в json.
К слову, смог получить id обратившись вот так
                    if let id = jsonResult["response"][1]["id"].rawString() {
                        print("\(id) ID")
Принципиальное различие - обращался через rawString(интуитивно, не понимаю какая в коде принципиальная разница). Похоже проблема где то у меня в процессе преобразования в json все же.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все правильно и ответ приходит как описано в [официальной документации](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=wall.get), то разобрать его необходимо так:

```
let id = ["response"][1]["id"].intValue
```

не 0, т.к. первый элемент - количество записей(вроде).

`.int` возвращает опциональный тип и только если это число/`Bool`, иначе `nil`. `.intValue` также работает и со `String`, если же не может разобрать (если аргумент `Array/ Dictionary/null`), то возвращает 0. К примеру, если на входе число/`Bool/String/Array` и что возвращает:

```
"id":219
.int:      Optional(219) //Вот в этом случае можете if let...
.intValue: 219

"id":true
.int:      Optional(1)
.intValue: 1

"id":"219"
.int:      nil //не работает со String
.intValue: 219

"id":[1, 219]
.int:      nil
.intValue: 0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно так и сработало. Вместо .int -> .intValue, вместо .string -> .stringValue. Единственное, что с такой конструкцией он отказывается работать с if let. Если вам не сложно, поясните почему в данном случае .intValue отдает значение, а int нет?

Comment: @George обновил ответ, т.к. не влезло в комментарий